# How to display negative limits for an integral in LaTeX?

Tags: python, integral

I am having issues displaying negative limits for an integral.

My code is in Python:

```py
f"Use substitution to evaluate the definite integral $_\\displaystyle\\int_{stra}^{strb} {latex(f)}\\,dx$_."
```

It displays like this:

[image: result]

Additional info:

- `latex(f)` returns `sympy.latex(f)`
- `f = c*x*((d*x**2)+e)**g`
- `stra` is the string version of a variable `a` which is an integer between `-3` and `3`.
- `strb` is the string version of a variable `b` which is an integer between `-5` and `5`.
- I made the variables strings to see if it made a difference as it was doing the same thing when the variables were integers.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify how `latex(f)`, `stra`, and `strb` are defined.

Comment: Are you missing the underscore?  `\int_{stra}`?

Comment: this seems to be a python rather than latex question, you need to generate `\int_{-6}^{-34}` not `\int_-6^-34` (also you should not normally have `\displaystyle` in a document)

Comment: Your problem kooks more a Python one than a LatTeX one. Using `int_{{{stra}}}^{{{strb}}}` instead of `int_{stra}^{strb}` should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks projetmbc that did it! I'm very new to using latex with python so I wasn't sure which part I was getting wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand your python code. But here's how I would input the integral expression using just simple TeX and LaTeX macros:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\begin{document}
\[
\int_{-6}^{-3} 4x{(17x^2+9)}^3\,dx
\quad\mbox{or}\quad
\int_{-6}^{-3}\!\! 4x{(17x^2+9)}^3\,dx
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Observe that the second expression is very similar to the first. The only difference is that there is *less whitespace* between the integral symbol (including its limits) and the integrand.

Answer (score 0):

Since Python 3.6 **f-strings** (a string literal that is prefixed with `f` or `F`) provide a way to embed expressions inside string literals by including replacement fields, which are expressions delimited by curly braces `{}`. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

> The parts of the string outside curly braces are treated literally, except that any doubled curly braces `{{` or `}}` are replaced with the corresponding single curly brace.

So, if you want to interpolate an expression into a string literal that includes literal curly brace characters you will need three sets of braces as pointed out by @projetmbc in the comments.

There's no need to convert `a` and `b` to string.

## MWE

**integral.py**

```py
import sympy

x = sympy.symbols('x')
a, b, c, d, e, g = -6, -3, 4, 17, 9, 3
f = c*x*((d*x**2) + e)**g

src = fr"""\documentclass{{standalone}}

\begin{{document}}
Use substitution to evaluate the definite integral
$\displaystyle\int_{{{a}}}^{{{b}}} {sympy.latex(f)}\,dx$.
\end{{document}}"""

with open('integral.tex', mode='w') as fobj:
    print(src, file=fobj)
```

When the Python script above is run it generates the following file:

**integral.tex**

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}
Use substitution to evaluate the definite integral
$\displaystyle\int_{-6}^{-3} 4 x \left(17 x^{2} + 9\right)^{3}\,dx$.
\end{document}
```

which renders:

[image: Rendered output]